# __NSPlaceholderDictionary crash when overriding UIFonts

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, uifont

i am overriding all fonts in my app using the following code. it took me hours to figure this out but with the fonts overridden, normal functionality would break (ex: long press gesture on a `UITableViewCell`), and all instances of `UIBarButtonItem` truncated showing only `...` in the nav bar.

the crash always resulted in

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

```
//.h 
@interface UIFont (SystemFontOverride)
@end

//.m 
@implementation UIFont (SystemFontOverride)
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"
+ (UIFont *)boldSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Regular" size:fontSize];
}

+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:fontSize];
}

+ (UIFont *)italicSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-ThinItalic" size:fontSize];
}
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

@end
```

am i doing something wrong? is there a better way to override fonts without manually setting each label, segment control, etc... this app wont be on the app store so im open to ANY suggestions.

bonus question, `#pragma clang diagnostic pop` and `#pragma clang diagnostic push`. i understand its saving the state of the compiler, silence a warning, and then revert the state. can i get away with just `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored`?

Comment: Never override methods in an Objective-C category. It's undefined behavior and results in bad things happening.

Comment: any suggestions on how to change all my fonts. ive tinkered with UI_APPEARENCE but the downside to that is not all my labels are the same font size and i cant change font without specifying a size

Comment: Instead of trying to replace the standard `UIFont` methods in a category, add your own methods to the category. Example - instead of overriding `boldSystemFontOfSize:`, name it `myBoldSystemFontOfSize:`. Or use `UI_APPEARANCE` or change a label's font size using `label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:newSize];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the sake of marking this as answered, im following rmaddy's comment

> Instead of trying to replace the standard UIFont methods in a category, add your own methods to the category. Example - instead of overriding boldSystemFontOfSize:, name it myBoldSystemFontOfSize:. Or use UI_APPEARANCE or change a label's font size using label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:newSize];

i went the `UI_APPEARANCE` route

```
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize]];
```

if your labels require different font size, this might be problematic, fortunately, the labels i need to change were all the same fontsize

Answer (score 0):

You also could subclass UILabel and use it everywhere:

For example call setFont in the init method,

then simply find&replace UILabel with your Subclass